# Adding in max() to query with many joins kills performance - how to optimise?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Let me preface this by saying I'm working in SSMS2016, and that my SQL is not the greatest.

I have a query with quite a few joins, which runs in slow-but-bearable 20-odd seconds.

I'd like to add a column which is basically the max value of the row_number in the CCR subquery (the 2 lines commented out in the code), however it massively impacts query time (60+ seconds for 1000 records). Is there any way I can get the required column without the huge jump in run time, and any way I can clean up the query in general?

```
SELECT DISTINCT AWI.*
FROM
(SELECT 
    4 'SORT'
    , CCR.URN
    , CCR.SPECIAL_COMMENT
    , SL.SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE
    , CASE WHEN SL.LOAD_CLOSED = 'Y' THEN SL.ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE_TIME ELSE NULL END AS 'ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE'
    , SL.LOAD_CLOSED
    , SH.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM 'SHIPPING_LOAD'
--  , MAX(CCR.RNK) OVER(PARTITION BY CCR.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM) 'CTNS_ON_LOAD'
    , SH.CARRIER
    , SH.CARRIER_SERVICE 'SERVICE'
    , IWI.PARENT_INSTR 'WORK_UNIT'
    , IWI.CONDITION 'WORK_STATUS'
    , IWI.WORK_TYPE
    , sl.LOCATION 'DOCK_DOOR'
    , CCR.CONTAINER_ID
    , SC.LOCATION 'FROM_LOC'
    , IWI.TO_LOC
    , SH.SHIP_TO
    , G.DESCRIPTION 'COUNTRY'


    , case  when SL.LEADING_STS = '201' then '[201] In Wave'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '300' then '[300] Picking Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '301' then '[301] In Picking'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '400' then '[400] Packing Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '401' then '[401] In Packing'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '500' then '[500] Pack and Hold Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '600' then '[600] Staging Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '650' then '[650] Loading Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '700' then '[700] Ship Confirm Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '800' then '[800] Load Confirm Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '900' then '[900] Closed'
            END AS 'LEADING_STS'
    , case  when SL.TRAILING_STS = '201' then '[201] In Wave'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '300' then '[300] Picking Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '301' then '[301] In Picking'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '400' then '[400] Packing Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '401' then '[401] In Packing'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '500' then '[500] Pack and Hold Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '600' then '[600] Staging Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '650' then '[650] Loading Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '700' then '[700] Ship Confirm Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '800' then '[800] Load Confirm Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '900' then '[900] Closed'
            END AS 'TRAILING_STS'
    , CCR.CONTAINER_TYPE
    , DIMS.WEIGHT
    , DIMS.LENGTH
    , DIMS.WIDTH
    , DIMS.HEIGHT

FROM
    IA_WORK_INSTRUCTION IWI
JOIN
    (SELECT INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM, SHIP_TO, CARRIER, CARRIER_SERVICE, SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM, SHIP_TO_COUNTRY FROM SHIPMENT_HEADER) SH
    ON SH.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = IWI.INTERNAL_NUM
JOIN
    (SELECT c1.INTERNAL_WORK_INST_NUM, c1.CONTAINER_ID, c1.URN, c1.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM, c1.SPECIAL_COMMENT, sc1.container_type, H1.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM
--  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY H1.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM ORDER BY C1.CONTAINER_ID DESC) 'RNK'
    FROM CARTON_CALLOFF_REQUEST c1
    join shipping_container sc1
    on sc1.internal_container_num = c1.internal_container_num
    JOIN SHIPMENT_HEADER H1 
    ON H1.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = SC1.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM
    ) CCR
    ON CCR.INTERNAL_WORK_INST_NUM = IWI.PARENT_INSTR
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT IDENTIFIER, DESCRIPTION FROM GENERIC_CONFIG_DETAIL WHERE RECORD_TYPE = 'COUNTRY') G
    ON G.IDENTIFIER = SH.SHIP_TO_COUNTRY
JOIN
    (SELECT INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM, PARENT, LOCATION FROM SHIPPING_CONTAINER) SC
    ON SC.PARENT = CCR.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM AND SC.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = SH.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM, WEIGHT, LENGTH, WIDTH, HEIGHT FROM SHIPPING_CONTAINER WHERE CONTAINER_ID IS NOT NULL) DIMS
    ON DIMS.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM = CCR.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM
JOIN
    (SELECT s1.INTERNAL_LOAD_NUM, s1.LEADING_STS, s1.TRAILING_STS, s1.LOAD_CLOSED, s1.ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE_TIME, s1.SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE, s1.DOCK_DOOR, l1.location FROM SHIPPING_LOAD s1 join location l1 on l1.object_id = s1.dock_door WHERE L1.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = 'DOOR') SL
    ON SL.INTERNAL_LOAD_NUM = SH.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM 

) AWI

WHERE AWI.WORK_TYPE = 'CALL OFF PICK'
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using derived tables versus explicit joins? Also, the DISTINCT in those sub-queries will also slow down your query.

Comment: @scsimon I'm several iterations into this query and I was trying different things to try and make it run faster. I think I remember it running in about the same time as explicit joins, so I just left it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You might try replacing the Partition and Over() with Group By.
Please let us know if you face any issues even after adding the Group By.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AWI.*
FROM
(SELECT 
    4 'SORT'
    , CCR.URN
    , CCR.SPECIAL_COMMENT
    , SL.SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE
    , CASE WHEN SL.LOAD_CLOSED = 'Y' THEN SL.ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE_TIME ELSE NULL END AS 'ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE'
    , SL.LOAD_CLOSED
    , SH.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM 'SHIPPING_LOAD'
    , MAX(CCR.RNK) 
    , SH.CARRIER
    , SH.CARRIER_SERVICE 'SERVICE'
    , IWI.PARENT_INSTR 'WORK_UNIT'
    , IWI.CONDITION 'WORK_STATUS'
    , IWI.WORK_TYPE
    , sl.LOCATION 'DOCK_DOOR'
    , CCR.CONTAINER_ID
    , SC.LOCATION 'FROM_LOC'
    , IWI.TO_LOC
    , SH.SHIP_TO
    , G.DESCRIPTION 'COUNTRY'


    , case  when SL.LEADING_STS = '201' then '[201] In Wave'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '300' then '[300] Picking Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '301' then '[301] In Picking'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '400' then '[400] Packing Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '401' then '[401] In Packing'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '500' then '[500] Pack and Hold Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '600' then '[600] Staging Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '650' then '[650] Loading Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '700' then '[700] Ship Confirm Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '800' then '[800] Load Confirm Pending'
            when SL.LEADING_STS = '900' then '[900] Closed'
            END AS 'LEADING_STS'
    , case  when SL.TRAILING_STS = '201' then '[201] In Wave'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '300' then '[300] Picking Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '301' then '[301] In Picking'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '400' then '[400] Packing Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '401' then '[401] In Packing'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '500' then '[500] Pack and Hold Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '600' then '[600] Staging Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '650' then '[650] Loading Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '700' then '[700] Ship Confirm Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '800' then '[800] Load Confirm Pending'
            when SL.TRAILING_STS = '900' then '[900] Closed'
            END AS 'TRAILING_STS'
    , CCR.CONTAINER_TYPE
    , DIMS.WEIGHT
    , DIMS.LENGTH
    , DIMS.WIDTH
    , DIMS.HEIGHT

FROM
    IA_WORK_INSTRUCTION IWI
JOIN
    (SELECT INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM, SHIP_TO, CARRIER, CARRIER_SERVICE, SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM, SHIP_TO_COUNTRY FROM SHIPMENT_HEADER) SH
    ON SH.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = IWI.INTERNAL_NUM
JOIN
    (SELECT c1.INTERNAL_WORK_INST_NUM, c1.CONTAINER_ID, c1.URN, c1.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM, c1.SPECIAL_COMMENT, sc1.container_type, H1.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY H1.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM ORDER BY C1.CONTAINER_ID DESC) 'RNK'
    FROM CARTON_CALLOFF_REQUEST c1
    join shipping_container sc1
    on sc1.internal_container_num = c1.internal_container_num
    JOIN SHIPMENT_HEADER H1 
    ON H1.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = SC1.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM
    ) CCR
    ON CCR.INTERNAL_WORK_INST_NUM = IWI.PARENT_INSTR
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT IDENTIFIER, DESCRIPTION FROM GENERIC_CONFIG_DETAIL WHERE RECORD_TYPE = 'COUNTRY') G
    ON G.IDENTIFIER = SH.SHIP_TO_COUNTRY
JOIN
    (SELECT INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM, PARENT, LOCATION FROM SHIPPING_CONTAINER) SC
    ON SC.PARENT = CCR.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM AND SC.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM = SH.INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_NUM
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM, WEIGHT, LENGTH, WIDTH, HEIGHT FROM SHIPPING_CONTAINER WHERE CONTAINER_ID IS NOT NULL) DIMS
    ON DIMS.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM = CCR.INTERNAL_CONTAINER_NUM
JOIN
    (SELECT s1.INTERNAL_LOAD_NUM, s1.LEADING_STS, s1.TRAILING_STS, s1.LOAD_CLOSED, s1.ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE_TIME, s1.SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE, s1.DOCK_DOOR, l1.location FROM SHIPPING_LOAD s1 join location l1 on l1.object_id = s1.dock_door WHERE L1.TEMPLATE_FIELD1 = 'DOOR') SL
    ON SL.INTERNAL_LOAD_NUM = SH.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM 

GROUP BY
     CCR.URN
     , CCR.SPECIAL_COMMENT
     , SL.SCHEDULED_SHIP_DATE
     , CASE WHEN SL.LOAD_CLOSED = 'Y' THEN SL.ACTUAL_SHIP_DATE_TIME ELSE 
        NULL END 
     , SL.LOAD_CLOSED
     , SH.SHIPPING_LOAD_NUM 
     , SH.CARRIER
     , SH.CARRIER_SERVICE
     , IWI.PARENT_INSTR
     , IWI.CONDITION
     , IWI.WORK_TYPE
     , sl.LOCATION
     , CCR.CONTAINER_ID
     , SC.LOCATION
     , IWI.TO_LOC
     , SH.SHIP_TO
     , G.DESCRIPTION
     , SL.LEADING_STS
     , TRAILING_STS 
     , CCR.CONTAINER_TYPE
     , DIMS.WEIGHT
     , DIMS.LENGTH
     , DIMS.WIDTH
     , DIMS.HEIGHT
) AWI

WHERE AWI.WORK_TYPE = 'CALL OFF PICK'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question at all and would change the result set completely.

Comment: I tried to modify the query there for you. Since I dont have the table structure locally, I am not able to test the script. Could you check and let me know

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question, I was merely commenting that applying an aggregate and applying an aggregate in a window function isn't the same and the result set would differ greatly.